# How can I echo a COUNT query

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql, count

I'm new to mySQL and as such am just looking for a very simple COUNT query which I haven't found explained online with any real clarity.

What I'm looking to do is

COUNT the number of rows in my PASSENGER table where groupID = 0, and then be able to echo the numerical value that the count will return, how can I do this?

Comment: There is a chapter in the MySQL manual on counting rows; see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html

Comment: @ceejayoz It is basic you're right, i'm very new to mySQL and as such have been experimenting! Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: @silly Nope, used to be a JAVA programmer now introducing myself to PHP and mySQL, so taking a little while to get my head round it! Some advanced functions I've done well with, some basic ones have stumped me, such as this!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM PASSENGER WHERE groupID = 0;";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['c']; //Here is your count
```

Comment: Although should be using mysqli_ and not mysql_!

Comment: @NigelRen, True. you should either use PDO or MySQLi functions.

Answer (score 2):

```
//get result
$data = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total FROM PASSENGER WHERE groupID = 0");
$info = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);

//output result
echo "Rows found :" . $info["total"];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as result FROM passenger WHERE groupID = 0";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo "Number is: ", $row;
```

Comment: Heh, I love how similar mine and Starx answers are, almost to the letter :)

Comment: Surely mine should get an upvote for using mysql_fetch_row :)

Comment: `mysql_fetch_row` returns a numeric array, not an associative array.

Comment: Heh, your right, fail! Been a while since i've written mysql_x stuff to be honest.

Comment: I guess last line will be just  echo $row;

Comment: @Md.ShohanHossain: Without running any tests, I think `echo $row;` will output `Array`.  You probably want `echo $row[0];`.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PASSENGER WHERE GROUPID = 0;`

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers sums this up pretty neat. Just want to add, in case you actually need the data from your passenger table later on in your script, it would be prudent not to make two seperate calls to get the count and the data. The best way to do this would be:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM PASSENGER WHERE groupID=0";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$result_count = mysql_num_rows($result);
?>
```

As opposed to: `SELECT PASSENGER.*, COUNT(*) as passenger_count FROM PASSENGER WHERE groupID=0`